# I'm learning how to use Vagrant and I was trying to run a python script

Tags: python, vagrant, git-bash

On GitBash I ran

```
vagrant up  
vagrant ssh  
Python abc.py
```

It gave an error

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory
```

I have tried `dos2unix` command it didn't work

python version:

```
Python 2.7.12+
```

How can I get past this error message?

Comment: Can you run which python and see what the result is?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` adds `python` path to your PATH

```
export PATH=/c/path/to/Python:$PATH
```

Then launch your bash again, and see if the error persists.

If the vagrant ssh uses a different bash resource file, type (in the same bash "`vagrant ssh`" session)

```
echo export PATH=/c/path/to/Python:\$PATH >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then try again `Python abc.py`

Comment: I tried the above steps. Didn't seem to solve the issue

Comment: @SomyaAgarwal what exact path did you add?

Comment: vagrant is using a different bash resource file so i typed the command you mentioned above

echo export PATH=/c/path/to/Python:\$PATH >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

Comment: /c/path/to/Python:/c/path/to/Python:/c/path/to/Python:/c/path/to/Python:/c/path/to/Python:/c/path/to/Python:/vagrant/Tools/autotest:/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/c/path/to/Python:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/jsbsim/src

Comment: Make sure it is the parent folder which has the python executable

Answer (score 0):

> ‘python\r’:

You've got screwed up line endings in your python script. Has nothing to do with vagrant, but what you used to write your code.

Open up vim in your ssh session and fix the line endings